# When is the preposition combination 'on in' used together?

Tags: prepositions

[Source.](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=glFaV-Ra8cjwB6HtjtAI#q=miley%20cyrus)

> Miley Cyrus and Liam Hemsworth are finally getting married **on in** Australia this summer.

Why it not same 'getting married in Australia'?

Another example:Virat Kohli playing on in the field.

This was written below an image of Virat.

Comment: The "married on in Australia" looks like a mistake to me, and indeed in [this article](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/tvshowbiz/article-3633747/Miley-Cyrus-Liam-Hemsworth-finally-getting-married-beach-Australia-summer.html) it seems to have been corrected even though the Google search result summary of that article said "on in".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your sentence

> Miley Cyrus and Liam Hemsworth are finally getting married on in Australia this summer.

I think the original was

> Miley Cyrus and Liam Hemsworth are finally getting married on *a beach* in Australia this summer.

It was an editing error.